# "Compared to" vs "as compared to"

Tags: word-choice, differences

Are both "compared to" and "as compared to" correct?

1. Microsoft has bigger market share **compared to** Apple.
2. This question is more difficult **as compared to** the previous one.

Comment: Probably, "are both ..."

Comment: why do we use the past tense of compare on these examples? not 'compare to, or 'as compare to'? What does the rule apply? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They are both correct, and different ways of saying the same thing.  However, neither way fits in your examples.  It is ungrammatical to use a comparative (e.g. *bigger* or *more difficult*) with *compared to*.  Either use a non-comparative adjective (e.g. *big* or *difficult*) with *as compared to* or simply *compared to*:

> Microsoft has a **large** market share **[as] compared to** Apple.
>
> This question is **difficult [as] compared to** the previous one.

Or use the comparative adjective, and replace *as compared to* with *than*:

> Microsoft has a **bigger** market share **than** Apple.
>
> This question is **more difficult than** the previous one.

Comment: And it would be even simpler to say: "Microsoft has a larger market share than Apple." and "This question is more difficult than the previous one."

Comment: @JLG True.  Interestingly, I had just started editing that part in right before your comment popped up!

Answer (score -2):

"As compared to" and "as compared with" are grammatically incorrect. Correct usage for comparisons of two things is either "compared to" or "compared with," according to the Merriam-Webster English dictionary. "Compared to" refers to two things that are not alike, and "compared with" is used to refer to two similar things. Insertion of the word "as" before either type of comparison is incorrect.